# A "unique": true index on MongoDB and Batch Insertion

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Let's say I created an index on `user_id`

```
db.members.createIndex( { "user_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

I have three questions:

1. Does having this `"unique": true` make batch insertions slower?
2. How is this different from "upsert"?
3. What happens when you try to batch insert that includes some duplicates? Does it just fail and rollback? Or does it just fail on those few that failed because of the unique check?

Answer (score 0):

Does having this "unique": true make batch insertions slower?

- Maintaining an index is always going to add some overhead to writes/updates while speeding up reads. Especially with "unique": true; its going to validate the constraint, so its going to be a tad slower than a regular index. But if "user_id" is going to be unique, then its the best way to ensure it.

How is this different from "upsert"?

- I believe the question here, what happens to cases where updates are being run with "upsert" : true? Then if there is an existing user_id, then it will just overwrite.

What happens when you try to batch insert that includes some duplicates? Does it just fail and rollback? Or does it just fail on those few that failed because of the unique check?

- The duplicate records will result in "duplicate record found error" unless "upsert" : true was set.

Comment: Thank you, so in the case where I don't care about overwriting as long as i have only a single unique item, what would be more efficient? just using "unique": true? or just using "upsert"? Or are they the same?

Comment: If the idea is to guarantee only a single unique item, its better to go with enforcing "unique":true.

Comment: The reason I say {"unique":true} index is better is because, down the line once you have huge number of rows, just doing upsert without index results in collection scan. The performance of those upserts will be inversely proportional to the number of rows in the table. So its always advisable to go with the index, eating out the latency/overhead is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Does having this "unique": true make batch insertions slower?**

It is an index so by definition yes it will. On insert the uniqueness of the records needs to be validated etc. Not sure we need to spend too much time on this question.

**2. How is this different from "upsert"?**

The question is what happens when you do updates with `upsert: true` option. As per the docs:

> To avoid inserting the same document more than once, only use upsert: true if the query field is
>   uniquely indexed.
>
> If all update() operations complete the query portion before any client successfully inserts data, and
>   there is no unique index on the name field, then each update operation may result in an insert.
>   To prevent MongoDB from inserting the same document more than once, create a unique index on the
>   name field.
>
> With a unique index, if multiple applications issue the same update with upsert: true, exactly
>   one update() would successfully insert a new document.
>   The remaining operations would either:
>
> • update the newly inserted document, or
>
> • fail when they attempted to insert a duplicate.
>
> If the operation fails because of a duplicate index key error, applications may retry the operation which
>   will succeed as an update operation. 
>   upsert:true with a Dotted _id Query

**3. What happens when you try to batch insert that includes some duplicates? Does it just fail and rollback? Or does it just fail on those few that failed because of the unique check?**

It depends. It will if you leave the default for the `ordered` option. But if you set that to **false**:

> If **ordered** is set to **false**, documents are inserted in an unordered format and may be reordered by mongod to increase performance. Applications should not depend on ordering of inserts if using an unordered insertMany().

and most importantly if an error occurs during bulk `insertMany`:

> With **ordered** to **false**, the insert operation would continue with any remaining documents.

[More on Unordered Inserts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#unordered-inserts)

[More on unique index with upsert:true](http://eecs.csuohio.edu/~sschung/cis612/MongoDB%20Update%20with%20upsert.pdf)